# XText DSL with lookbehind

Tags: eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext

I am stuck in writing a DSL using XText. Let us assume that I want to parse something like this:

```
A {
  B, //this comma is needed
  C, 
  D {E}, //comma is optional after a closing curly brace
  F {G}
  H
}
I,
J
```

It should be represented by the types Model and Class, where Model contains a list of classes.

What I do have currently is:

```
Model: (classes += Class)*
Class: name = ID ('{' (subclasses += Class) (',' subclasses += Class)* '}')?
```

This would work if classes must be delimited by a comma, independent from them having subclasses or not. However, since a Class can have subclasses bracketed by curly braces, a comma is not a must after a closing curly brace.

This means I need a grammar expressing the following:

```
Class: ID (',' Class | '{' subclasses += Class '}' ','? Class)?
```

Since I am not able to reference the containing rule, the Class rule reference inside Class will not work. I believe that there is a simple solution for this issue which I just can not see.

Edit: I belive a lookbehind would be a solution. However, it seems to me like this is not suppoerted in XText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like the following (+ a validation for the very last comma)

```
Model:
    ((classes+=ClassWithBraces|classes+=ClassWithComma)* classes+=ClassAtEnd?);

ClassWithComma returns Class:
    name=ID ","
;

ClassWithBraces returns Class:
    name=ID =>("{" ((classes+=ClassWithBraces|classes+=ClassWithComma)* classes+=ClassAtEnd?) "}") ","?
;

ClassAtEnd returns Class:
    name=ID
;
```

Comment: In your case `A {B{}} I` is allowed, but `A{}` not right?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that one time you are using `ClassAtEnd` as optional and the other time not.